# How to play audio at LG webos TV

Tags: javascript, audio, webos, television, lg

I have a web project and I trying to play audio at webos on LG TV. It working good at browser, but sadly have a huge lag on TV.

I'm trying to use http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library

**audio.js**

```
 var sounds = [ new Howl({
        urls: ['/assets/sounds/swipe.mp3']
    }),new Howl({
        urls: ['/assets/sounds/swipe2.mp3']
    }), new Howl({
        urls: ['/assets/sounds/click.mp3']
    })];
    $(document).on('mouseenter focus', '.video-item', function(){
        sounds[0].play();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.video-item', function(){
        sounds[2].play();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter focus', '.hvr-bob', function(){
        sounds[1].play();
    });
```

Comment: Are you able to find a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Audio`. If you check the source code of Howler, you'll see that they also use it with some extra checks, so if you just drop them, you're likely to get some performance improvements.

```
var sound = new Audio("/assets/sounds/message.wav");
$(document).on('click', '.video-item', function(){
    sound.play();
});
```

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: May be you know webAudioAPI wrapper similar to Howler?

Comment: I don't think you actually need that: you just play sounds, nothing from the complex howler functionality like sound sprites or whatever ;)

Comment: I play lot's of sounds. More similar to the game application. Needs more power man ;)